# Got this error "Cannot invoke \"Object.getClass()\" because \"callArgs[0]\" is null" in kibana Console

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

- got this error in **kibana console**

`Cannot invoke \"Object.getClass()\" because \"callArgs[0]\" is null`

- while executed this in **kibana devtools console**

```
POST <index_name>/_update_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "Field": "FieldValue"
    }
  },
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.Address.add(params.tag)",
    "lang": "painless",
    "params": {
      "tag":{
        "Field" : "ItsValue",
      }
    }
  }
}
```

- **Versions information**

```
kibana : 7.9.3
elasticsearch : 7.9.3
```